# Werror missing declarations in C++ with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am making a game using C++ with SFML lib and in my main I created couple functions. I know it is a bad manner to do that in main but yeah. when I try to compile the code I am getting error:

```
src/main.cpp: In function 'void create_platforms(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite> >&)':
src/main.cpp:12:6: error: no previous declaration for 'void create_platforms(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite> >&)' [-Werror=missing-declarations]
 void create_platforms(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>>& platforms)
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~src/Player.cpp:
 In member function 'void Player::gravity(sf::Time&, sf::FloatRect&)':
```

same goes to create_items and create_interface. I am not using any header file for main.cpp, can I just declare those in main.cpp? If so I would be glad if someone would help me how to do it.

```
void create_platforms(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>>& platforms)
{
    [...]
}

void create_items(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>>& healing_items)
{
    auto small_heart = std::make_unique<sf::Sprite>();
    small_heart->setTexture(*TextureManager::getTexture("heart"));
    small_heart->setPosition(320, 180);
    small_heart->setScale(0.4, 0.4);
    healing_items.emplace_back(std::move(small_heart));
}

void create_interface(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::Sprite>>& interface)
{
    auto life = std::make_unique<sf::Sprite>();`enter code here`
    life->setTexture(*TextureManager::getTexture("life"));
    life->setPosition(10, 530);
    interface.emplace_back(std::move(life));
}

int main()
{
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Did you made a bug report on https://www.sfml-dev.org/community.php ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can I just declare those in main.cpp?

Technically yes. What matters for the -Wmissing-declarations option is that a declaration is before definition. The file in which you put the declaration is irrelevant.

Note however that this may be against the spirit of the warning. It is unclear why you want to get warnings about missing declarations when you simultaneously want to not use a header.

If the function is intended to be used only within that translation unit, then you should declare it within an anonymous namespace. -Wmissing-declarations will not warn about functions in anonymous namespace.

Comment: `If the function is intended to be used only within that translation unit, then you should declare it within an anonymous namespace. ` I don't understand that statement. It can be in any namespace. If it must be restricted to not be visible outside of translation unit, function should be declared `static`, otherwise declarations available in other units should have to be made in namespace with same name

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie `It can be in any namespace.` Sure it **can**. But if it doesn't need to be used elsewhere, then it is easier to not give the namespace a name, because that introduces the possibility of name conflicts across separate translation units. `function should be declared static` What is the advantage of this compared to using anonymous namespace? As far as I know, it achieves the same thing effectively.

Comment: Edit to clarify: It is easier to not give the namespace a name because giving a name introduces possibility of name conflicts.

Comment: agree with that. Just  anonymous namespaces bring their own problem and advantages and should be treated with care...Not being complete equivalent to internal linkage specified with static,  for functions they still leave a mangled name in global symbol table, some uncareful use may cause ODR breach if they type declaration and their use with tempate specializations is troubled.

Comment: From OPs code I gathered that situation is opposite: those functions in main.cpp ARE to be used in Player.cpp, which would require declarations in that module